# Windows phone 7 Jump List control

Tags: windows-phone-7, jump-list

I have a question. In a windows phone 7, Will i be able to navigate from the jumplist control to another page. For example i have some data in the jumplist control, and then once i click on one of the data, will i be able to go to another page from there? if it is possible, can someone show me some links for it? sample codes would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ListPicker from the Silverlight Toolkit and use the SelectionChanged event.

Tutorial : http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth

Comment: but i have already implemented the jumplist.. and my project requires me to use jumplist.

Comment: Ok, it makes no difference, you probably an event based on the selection of an item

Comment: What jumplist are you using (what tool)? bewisephonecontrols?

Answer (score 0):

Download the project in this link an enhance by add selected index and page navigating option.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/news/developing-a-wp7-jump-list-control

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/windows-phone/jumplist.aspx?pageid=1

Comment: but I want the page that is navigated to,to be able to display the data that was in the jumplistcontrol. Will it work?

Comment: You want to display the data or you want t navigate to another page its better if you post the codes you are used